# new product type image of bundled product - children product price not insert in table sale_flat_quote_item and sale_flat_order_item

Tags: magento-1.7, product

I created a new product type image of bundled product and everything is work except the children product cannot insert the price in to database table salt_flat_quote_item and sale_flat_order_item. This turned out to give some problems in the order in the backend cannot show children price of this product. Do i have to call a function to get my children price?

this is my config file

```
<catalog>
<product>
<type>
  <formula translate="label" module="bank">
    <label>Formula Product</label>
    <model>bank/product_type_formula</model>
    <composite>1</composite>
    <allowed_selection_types>
      <simple/>
      <virtual/>
    </allowed_selection_types>
    <price_model>bank/product_type_formula_price</price_model>
    <index_data_retreiver>bank/catalogIndex_data_formula</index_data_retreiver>
    <index_priority>40</index_priority>
  </formula>
</type>
<options>
  <formula>
     <types>
        <select translate="label" module="bank">
           <label>Drop-down</label>
        </select>
        <radio translate="label" module="bank">
           <label>Radio Buttons</label>
        </radio>
        <checkbox translate="label" module="bank">
           <label>Checkbox</label>
        </checkbox>
        <multi translate="label" module="bank">
           <label>Multiple Select</label>
        </multi>
     </types>
  </formula>
</options>
```

Do I have to create more config or anything to extends bundle product.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I found the problem of this issue but still can't solved.

because my new product type cannot insert eav price_type into table catalog_product_entity_int  then I test to insert this data in the table by manual and child price of the product insert into table salt_flat_quote_item successful. I don't understand why my new product type is failed, anyone can help ?

Comment: What physical column (in the table) are you trying to add the child price to? What have you extended? We are going to see a lot more of your code to pinpoint the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `apply_to` attribute property for your `price_type` attribute using the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup` class. You can see this being done by the native "custom" product types; for example, see [*`app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/sql/bundle_setup/install-1.6.0.0.php`*](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/sql/bundle_setup/install-1.6.0.0.php#L554):

```
$installer->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 'price_type', array(
    'type'              => 'int',
    'backend'           => '',
    'frontend'          => '',
    'label'             => '',
    'input'             => '',
    'class'             => '',
    'source'            => '',
    'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'visible'           => false,
    'required'          => true,
    'user_defined'      => false,
    'default'           => '',
    'searchable'        => false,
    'filterable'        => false,
    'comparable'        => false,
    'visible_on_front'  => false,
    'used_in_product_listing' => true,
    'unique'            => false,
    'apply_to'          => 'bundle', // <------------- That's the one.
    'is_configurable'   => false
));
```